# SqlException was Unhandled An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am learning WinForms with C# and SQL. When I executed the code I got this error:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Here is the code:

```
string connetionString;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        connetionString = @"Data Source=desktop-brvgrif\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        cnn.Open();

        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataReader dataReader;
        String sql, Output = "";

        sql = "SELECT TutorialID,TutorialName from demotb";
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while(dataReader.Read())
        {
            Output = Output + dataReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(Output);

        dataReader.Close();
        command.Dispose();
        cnn.Close();
```

Comment: use try/catch around this code ... and find out more information about an Exception ... off-topic comment: are you aware about using/IDisposable ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to surround with try/catch ? @Selvin

Comment: Which line of code does it fail?

Comment: IDisposable is a mechanism for releasing unmanaged resources in the application.

Comment: dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

this line is failing. @jdweng

Comment: Open up SQL Server Management Studio and put query : "SELECT TutorialID,TutorialName from demot" into new query window.  The Error messages inside SSMS are 1000% times better than in c# and should provide the answer.

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehtab, you can surround your code with a Try-Catch block https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch, which will allow you to view details about what went wrong, and also react/handle it more gracefully than just letting the app crash.  

For example:
`try  
{  
 // Your code goes here  
}  
catch(Exception ex)  
{  
 string description = ex.Message;  
}  
finally  
{  
 // Clean up  
}  
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to include the name of the database (Initial Catalog) in your connection string.

```
connetionString = "Data Source=desktop-brvgrif\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseNameHere;Integrated Security=True";
```

[Connection String Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)